# Sorting array using pointers - C programming

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers

I have a problem with my code. I'm trying to sort an array using pointers. The problem I'm having is that when the program is sorting the array, it doesn't process the last input element. I'm not so comfortable using pointers as of yet. I'd appreciate some feedback. Here's the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 100

void inputarray(int *arr, int size);
void printarray(int *arr, int size);
void sortascending(int *arr, int size);

int main()
{
int array_size, array[MAX],choice;
    printf("Enter size of array:\n");
    scanf("%d",&array_size);
    array_size -= 1;
    printf("Enter elements:\n");
    inputarray(array, array_size);
    printf("Sorting scending:\n");
    sortascending(array, array_size);

    printarray(array, array_size);

    return 0;
}


void inputarray(int *arr, int size)
{
    int *arrayend = arr + size - 1;
    while(arr <= arrayend)
    {
        scanf("%d\n",arr++);
    }

}

void printarray(int *arr, int size)
{
    int *arrayend = arr + size-1;
    while(arr <= arrayend)
    {
        printf("%d", *(arr++));
    }
}


void sortascending(int *arr, int size)
{
    int *arrayend = arr + size - 1; 
    int i,j,t;
    for(i=0; i< size; i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1; j< size; j++)
        {
            if(*(arr+j)<*(arr+i))
            {
                t = *(arr+i);
                *(arr+i) = *(arr+j);
                *(arr+j) = t;
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

So basically if I enter 5 elements in the order 9,8,7,6,5, it will return 6,7,8,9, neglecting the last input element (which is 5). Any tips?

Comment: why do you subtract one from the requested array size?

Comment: `printf("%d", *(arr++));` You increment the pointer first, then read the value.

Comment: For some reason, the program allows more than requested input size. So if i enter 5, it allows me to input 6.

Comment: Your program would be simplified using indexing instead of pointer arithmetic. Ex: `arr[i]` instead of `*(arr+i)`

Comment: Your loops might be clearer and easier to handle if you use a 'for' loop from zero, < size

Comment: I realize that, but I'm trying to get more comfortable using pointers

Comment: You would still be using pointers, just controlling the loop in a way that makes more sense.

Comment: Returning to what you said above, "the program allows more than requested input size": if something like that happens, try to debug and understand why, rather than throwing a -1 at the problem.  Since you subtract 1 in two places, it makes sense that you're going to miss the last value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that after taking the array_size as input, you are decrementing it by 1, which is not necessary. This is because inside all your functions, you are doing     arrend = arr + size - 1 i.e., you are doing arrend = arr[size-1]. This works when size is actual size of array. Hence you need not decrement array_size inside the main function.
Working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 100

void inputarray(int *arr, int size);
void printarray(int *arr, int size);
void sortascending(int *arr, int size);

int main()
{
int array_size, array[MAX],choice;
printf("Enter size of array:\n");
scanf("%d",&array_size);
//no need to decrement size here
printf("Enter elements:\n");
inputarray(array, array_size);
printf("Sorting scending:\n");
sortascending(array, array_size);

printarray(array, array_size);

return 0;
}


void inputarray(int *arr, int size)
{
    int *arrayend = arr + size - 1;
    while(arr <= arrayend)
    {
        scanf("%d",arr++);
        //remove \n from above line

    }

}

void printarray(int *arr, int size)
{
    int *arrayend = arr + size-1;
    while(arr <= arrayend)
    {
        printf("%d", *(arr++));
    }
}


void sortascending(int *arr, int size)
{
    int *arrayend = arr + size - 1; 
    int i,j,t;
    for(i=0; i< size; i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1; j< size; j++)
        {
            if(*(arr+j)<*(arr+i))
            {
                t = *(arr+i);
                *(arr+i) = *(arr+j);
                *(arr+j) = t;
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Yes it works but for some reason it still allows size + 1 input even if the output is of specified size. It bugs me but yes the program works fine

Comment: Finally, I found it. You are doing:     scanf("%d\n",arr++) . The \n in this line is the reason for extra input. Just do scanf("%d",arr++). The scanf("%d\n",arr++) is expecting a non empty input (non newline input ) at the end. It means that read the number till non-whitespace character appear(ignore all whitespace and '\n' after the number). So removing it fixes the issue.